# Include CSS-Fonts from seperate Domain

Tags: html, css, font-face

I use fonts from [Fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) and include them with "@font-face" (CSS).
Please note: I don't want to use fonts which are given by the Google-Font-Api, so this isn't an alternative for me.

I have a lot of webprojects using the same fonts, JS-Fameworks, Images and such like. 
So I create a subdomain (e.g. mydata.mydomain.xy) which contains often used stuff.

Now I can simply include the stuff in different projects using copy and paste. E.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mydata.mydomain.xy/css/foo.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://mydata.mydomain.xy/css/bar.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydata.mydomain.xy/js/foo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydata.mydomain.xy/js/bar.js"></script>
```

Of course this works fine for me - exception: Fonts. 
It seems that the font-data (TTF, SVG, ...) have to be saved in a directory relative to the project-domain. The inclusion from another Domain only works in Chrome, not in Firefox or Opera (IE not tested yet). Is there a trick or an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, Firefox sees cross-domain fonts as a security problem, so they do not get included. Because of that, I've personally always used same-domain fonts or Google fonts, that are embed by any browser without a problem.

It seems there are some fixes to Firefox/Opera behaviour though. Some articles suggest modifying your .htaccess with something similiar to:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I haven't tested the sollution as I never needed it.

From quick Google:

- http://www.unseenrevolution.com/solution-firefox-font-face-cross-domain-problem/
- http://red-team-design.com/firefox-doesnt-allow-cross-domain-fonts-by-default/
- ... or just try it yourself, "firefox cross domain fonts"